# Limitar una o n sesion/es activa/s por usuario en Laravel 5.8?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

estoy tratando de limitar un registro a solo 1 dispositivos permitidos, y que al iniciar una nueva sesion, la sesion anterior automaticamente se cierre.

Encontre un post, pero la verdad es que intente hacer todo pero siguen mas de unasesion activa.

Anexo post:
https://www.jesusamieiro.com/limitar-a-una-sesion-por-usuario-en-laravel-5/

PD: Estoy comenzando con laravel, no se si omiti algo "obvio"

Sobreescribi ese metodo dentro de LoginController, pero consegui el resultado que ya había mencionado.

Comment: Además del controlador, hiciste la nueva migración (agregar la columna `session_id`)? También podes hacer uso de [Auth::logoutOtherDevices()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authentication#invalidating-sessions-on-other-devices)

Comment: Lo he resuelto, lei la documentación e indague un poquito mas.

Answer (score 1):

SOLUCIÓN:

- Descomentar en el kernel

`\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,`

- Sobre escribir el método "authenticated", lo copias de "AuthenticatesUsers"

`/**
     * The user has been authenticated.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  mixed  $user
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
    {
        //
    }`

- Sobreescribirlo en "LoginController" e inculir en la cabecera

`use Illuminate\Http\Request;`

- Dentro del metodo agregar

`\Auth::logoutOtherDevices(\request('password'));`

Así funciona, lo hice con Laravel 5.8